# sublime text 3 JS snippet on tab returns nothing

Tags: sublimetext3

Below is my snippet saved in **/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
], function($, _, Backbone) {

"use strict";

});
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>define</tabTrigger>
    <description>define</description>
</snippet>
```

In a JS file writing **define** then **tab** does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you have a '$' inside of your snippet definition. This seems to be causing your snippet to be invalid. You can escape the dollar sign it by using `\$` in its place (theres a section for it here http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html).

See a working example below:

```
    <snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
define([
    '${1:jquery}',
], function(${2:\$}) {

"use strict";

});
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>define</tabTrigger>
    <description>define</description>
</snippet>
```